# Can I install Ubuntu onto this laptop?

Tags: system-installation, laptop

So I'm still a complete noob with Ubuntu but while I'm learning to code I just have it running on a VM (version 15.04 64bit), which is great no problems but I want to be able to take it with me. So I've been looking at basic laptops that I can fully install it on and found this that I quite like: http://www.webhallen.com/se-sv/datorer_och_tillbehor/236067-asus_e502sa-dm049t_156_fhd_n3150-4gb-128gb_ssd-intel_hd_graphics-win_10 Would an install on this work? I've read some horror stories where Linux can mess peoples computers up and only work on certain brands. How true is this? Is it as daunting process as it sounds?

Many thanks guys :)

Comment: 15.04 is EOL. Update/upgrade/install anew 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Probably yes,

Linux packs a almost all drivers into it's kernel but Ubuntu uses mostly older kernels, so new peripherals can also be tricky but this should be a matter of time before any missing drivers get implemented into the kernel.

Nvidea drivers can also be painful to install, they keep their driver information closed, so open source initiatives as nouveau try to back engineer these closed drivers.

Before you install there's always an option to use a live USB running Ubuntu, to see how it goes. This ruins nothing, nor it will leave any traces on your PC !!
If you are booting first in windows try "Rufus" or "USBwriter.exe" for windows to write the Ubuntu ISO to.

As a last tip: try to make an image of the Windows which is pre installed on this PC ( example using Clonezilla) . You might need it later. Ubuntu en linux however should install perfectly alongside the existing windows OS. The other way is a bit difficult, but is is possible.

In general there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Computers can never be completely "messed up" by a Linux install. Even if Linux won't boot, you'll still be able to boot Windows, and if GRUB doesn't work (highly unlikely) then you'll still be able to repair the Windows bootloader and boot Windows again.

You can also test Linux on your computer first by preparing a bootable DVD or flash drive, and if your computer can boot from that then there's a high chance that Linux will work once you've installed it.

Nevertheless I'd recommend a full disk backup (preferably an image) if you're particularly concerned and if you've only got one computer then make sure that you have a reliable way to boot your system in the event that it won't boot from the hard drive.